# Blind Assassin: meaning of ygnirod, snilfard and Sakiel-Norn

Tags: the-blind-assassin

There is a sci-fi story within the novel *[The Blind Assassin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blind_Assassin)*, it features the city of Sakiel-Norn and its hierarchy system of Ygnirods and Snilfards. Are those words simply made up, or are they references to something or some anagrams I missed?

Comment: FWIW and to those interested, [this](http://www.e-reading.org.ua/chapter.php/79451/12/Atwood_-_The_Blind_Assassin.html) is the short story within TBA. Personally, I can't think of (or find) anything etymological or hidden and most people seem to believe they're nonsensical references intended to conjure imagery similar to, say, Jabberwocky.

Comment: Apart from saying they are sounding kind of Norse, I agree with Josh.

Answer (score 1):

Well all literature is "made up", but I get what you mean. You're asking if those words have any hidden etymology, but to be blunt I would say the answer is no.

Having said that, Ygnirods can be seen as a homophonic play on the word 'Ignorant' as they are the lower class type on Sakiel-norn and thus seen as ignorant to, and of, the Snilfard way of life. The word ignorant has many associations with lower class structures, and generally means someone who doesn't know of or understand something.

Snilfard, on the other hand, isn't an obvious derivative I can place but perhaps can be explained as a compound. 'Snil' could be seen as similar to snarl perhaps, which an onomatopoeic word expressing disgust or disdain, and 'fard' sounds similar to either 'facade' or 'farce' depending on your accent. Both of these words words mean a cover or pretence, essentially something not real or true. Put those two elements together and you have something fake which looks down on others... exactly as the Snilfards do.

Well, I hope this helps.

P.s. This is just an opinion, so I don't have anything to "back it up" with, so feel free to take it for what it's worth. I was just trying to help.

Comment: This appears to be headcanon (i.e. your own personal interpretation of what they mean and why). Without anything to back this up, what's to say that Atwood had any of this in mind?